# Merge array of hashes, keeping duplicate values as arrays

Tags: ruby, array, hash-map

I am working on [a Ruby gem](https://github.com/bradleymarques/gimme_wikidata) to pull data from the [Wikidata API](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Wikidata:Main_Page).  The data is deeply nested, as it contains a lot of repetition.

I have written a piece of Ruby (sans Rails) code that enables an array of hashes to be merged together, with any duplicate key-value pairs being stored as an array under the same key.

For example:

```
[{:a=>1, :b=>2}, {:b=>3, :c=>4}, {:d=>5, :a=>6}].merge_hashes
```

gives:

```
{:a=>[1, 6], :b=>[2, 3], :c=>4, :d=>5}
```

I began with the following:

```
class Array
  def merge_hashes
    raise StandardError.new "Array is not an Array of Hashes" unless self.all? {|e| e.is_a? Hash}
    self.each_with_object({}) do |el, h|
      el.each do |k, v|
        if h[k].nil?
          h[k] = v
        else
          h[k] = Array.new([h[k]]) << v
          h[k] = h[k].flatten
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

And refactored to:

```
class Array
def merge_hashes
    raise StandardError.new "Array is not an Array of Hashes" unless self.all? {|e| e.is_a? Hash}
    self.each_with_object({}) { |el, h| el.each { |k, v| h[k].nil? ? h[k] = v : h[k] = (Array.new([h[k]]) << v).flatten } }
  end 
end
```

Are there any other improvements I could make?  Is that an acceptable exception to throw?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the refactor is barely readable, the first version is better. Anyway, if you use functional abstractions, instead of doing a imperative processing from scratch, algorithms tend to be more clear.

In this case, we can use the abstraction [Enumerable#map_by](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/rubyworks/facets/Enumerable#map_by-instance_method) (a `group_by` variation where you can control both the grouping function and the accumulated values) and write:

```
require 'facets'

class Array
  def merge_hashes
    flat_map(&:to_a).map_by { |k, v| [k, v] }
  end 
end
```

Note that this snippet always returns an array as a value, instead of the scalar/list you have.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and for the link to facets; I didn't know about it.

Comment: Huh, I see your point about the mixed data types.  Thanks for the good advice.

Answer (score 1):

I've tried to simplify assignment condition (splat operator is used instead of `#flatten`):

```
class Array
  def merge_hashes_alt
    # ...
    self.each_with_object({}) do |el, h|
      el.each { |k, v| h[k] = h[k] ? [*h[k]] << v : v }
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: I think this is good, because it doesn't check for `nil?` explicitly and only has one `h[k] =` assignment.  In addition, it gets rid of the `Array.new()` and the `flatten`, as you mentioned.